# C\C++ type name highlight for VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there built-in color scheme editor or extension for highlight struct\type names available for Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons struct names and types was not highlighted on my PC. Highlight comes a bit later.